# IVP Wave Equation $u_{tt} = 4u_{xx} + \sin(ct)\cos(x)$ (PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> $$u_{tt} = 4u_{xx} + \sin(ct)\cos(x),\ {-1}<x<1, t>0 $$ 
>   $$u(0,x) = u_t(0,x) = 0, \ x \ge 0$$

**Attempt:**

For

> $$u_{tt} = 4u_{xx},\ {-1}<x<1, t>0$$ 
>   $$u(0,x) = \sin(x),\ u_t(0,x) = \cos(x) ,\ x≥0$$

we have the method from the textbook,

$\varphi(x) = \sin(x)$, $\psi(x) = \cos(x)$

$$u(x,t) = f(x+4t) + g(x-4t)$$

$$\varphi(x) = f(x) + g(x),\ \psi(x) = 4f'(x) - 4g'(x)$$

$$\varphi' = f' + g',\ \frac{1}{4\psi} = f' - g'$$

$$ f' = \frac{\varphi' + \psi/4}{2},\ g' = \frac{\varphi' - \psi/4}{2} $$

\begin{align} 
f(v) &= \frac{\varphi(v)}{2} + \frac12\int_{0}^{v=x+4t}\psi(s)ds + A \\
g(v) &= \frac{\varphi(w)}{2} - \frac18\int_{0}^{w=x-4t}\psi(s)ds + B 
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
u(x,t) &= f(v) + g(w) \\
&= \frac{\varphi(x+4t) + \varphi(x-4t)}{2} + \frac18\int_{x-4t}^{x+4}t\psi(s)\ ds \\
&= \frac{\sin(x+4t) + \sin(x-4t)}{2} + \frac18\int_{x-4t}^{x+4t}\cos(s)\ ds \\
&= \frac{\sin^2x - \sin^2(4t)}{2} + \frac18\big(\cos(x+4t) – \cos(x-4t)\big) \\
&= \frac{\sin^2x - \sin^2(4t)}{2} - \frac{\sin(x)\sin(4t)}{4}
\end{align}

For the same problem with remainder function of one variable such as

> $$ u_{tt} = 4u_{xx} + \cos(2t),\  {-1}<x<1, t>0$$ 
>   $$u (0,x) = \sin(x),\ u_t(0,x) = \cos(x),\ x≥0 $$

we verify that adding 
$$\frac14 \iint \cos(2t)\ dt\ dt = -\frac{\cos(2t)}{4} $$

to the previous solution is enough. Let $U(x,t)$ be the previous solution:

LHS: 
\begin{align}
u_{tt} &= \left(U - \frac{\cos(2t)}{4}\right)_{tt} \\ &= U_{tt} - \left(\frac{\cos(2t)}{4}\right)_{tt} \\ &= U_{tt} + \cos(2t)\end{align}

RHS: 
\begin{align} 4u_{xx} + \cos(2t) &= 4\left(U - \frac{\cos(2t)}{4}\right)_{xx} + \cos(2t) \\ &= 4U_{xx} + \cos(2t) \\ &= U_{tt} + \cos(2t) \end{align}

So 
\begin{align} u(x,t) &= U - \frac{\cos(2t)}{4} \\ &= \frac{\sin2x - \sin2(4t)}{2} - \frac{\sin(x)\sin(4t)}{4} - \frac{\cos(2t)}{4} \end{align}

But if I tried it with $u_{tt} = 4u_{xx} + \sin(ct)\cos(x)$ I just get a similar PDE with the same amount of variables.

Comment: Maybe others can read what you have written, but I find it almost impossible to do. Could you reformat your post using \sin, \cos. Also, having only one equality on each line would help. You can use \begin{align} to align everything nicely

Answer (score 0):

Let $\begin{cases}p=x+2t\\q=x-2t\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_x=u_pp_x+u_qq_x=u_p+u_q$

$u_{xx}=(u_p+u_q)_x=(u_p+u_q)_pp_x+(u_p+u_q)_qq_x=u_{pp}+u_{pq}+u_{pq}+u_{qq}=u_{pp}+2u_{pq}+u_{qq}$

$u_t=u_pp_t+u_qq_t=2u_p-2u_q$

$u_{tt}=(2u_p-2u_q)_t=(2u_p-2u_q)_pp_t+(2u_p-2u_q)_qq_t=4u_{pp}-4u_{pq}-4u_{pq}+4u_{qq}=4u_{pp}-8u_{pq}+4u_{qq}$

$\therefore4u_{pp}-8u_{pq}+4u_{qq}=4u_{pp}+8u_{pq}+4u_{qq}+\sin\dfrac{c(p-q)}{4}\cos\dfrac{p+q}{2}$

$u_{pq}=-\dfrac{1}{32}\sin\dfrac{(c+2)p-(c-2)q}{4}-\dfrac{1}{32}\sin\dfrac{(c-2)p-(c+2)q}{4}$

$u(p,q)=F(p)+G(q)-\dfrac{1}{32(c+2)(c-2)}\sin\dfrac{(c+2)p-(c-2)q}{4}-\dfrac{1}{32(c+2)(c-2)}\sin\dfrac{(c-2)p-(c+2)q}{4}$

$u(t,x)=F(x+2t)+G(x-2t)-\dfrac{\sin ct\cos x}{16(c+2)(c-2)}$

$u_t(t,x)=2F_x(x+2t)-2G_x(x-2t)-\dfrac{c\cos ct\cos x}{16(c+2)(c-2)}$

$u(0,x)=0$ , $u_t(0,x)=0$ :

$\begin{cases}F(x)+G(x)=0\\2F_x(x)-2G_x(x)=\dfrac{c\cos x}{16(c+2)(c-2)}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}F(x)+G(x)=0\\F(x)-G(x)=\dfrac{c\sin x}{32(c+2)(c-2)}+C\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}F(x)=\dfrac{c\sin x}{64(c+2)(c-2)}+\dfrac{C}{2}\\G(x)=-\dfrac{c\sin x}{64(c+2)(c-2)}-\dfrac{C}{2}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(t,x)=\dfrac{c\sin(x+2t)}{64(c+2)(c-2)}+\dfrac{C}{2}-\dfrac{c\sin(x-2t)}{64(c+2)(c-2)}-\dfrac{C}{2}-\dfrac{\sin ct\cos x}{16(c+2)(c-2)}=\dfrac{c\sin2t\cos x}{32(c+2)(c-2)}-\dfrac{\sin ct\cos x}{16(c+2)(c-2)}$

Comment: Particular solution is $u_p=-\frac{\sin ct\cos x}{c^2-4}$. It's easy to find with ansatz $u=A\sin ct\cos x$. Then final answer is 
$u=\frac{c \sin{\left( 2 t\right) } \cos{(x)}}{2 \left( {{c}^{2}}-4\right) }-\frac{\sin{\left( c t\right) } \cos{(x)}}{{{c}^{2}}-4}$.