# Is the solution of $ u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+xt $ correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, alternative-proof, initial-value-problems, greens-theorem

Consider the following $ u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+xt,\\ u(x,0)=0,\\ u_t(x,0)=\sin (x)$

and find the solution.

Solution.

We have that $u(x,t)$ is given by $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(g(x+ct)+g(x-ct))+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}h(u)du+\frac{1}{2c}\iint_\Delta f(y,s)dA,\cdots\cdots (1)$$ where $\Delta $ is a triangle with vertex $(x-ct,0),(x+ct,0),(x,t)$.

Thus in our case, $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\sin(u)du+\frac{1}{2c}\iint_\Delta xt \ dA.$

Using Green Theorem we have that $\frac{1}{2c}\iint_\Delta xt \ dA=\frac{1}{2}[\cos(x_0+ct)-\cos(x_0-ct)-2cu(x_0,t_0)],$ where I took a point $(x_0,t_0)$ to be able to integrate  using the theorem.

and

$\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\sin(u)du=\frac{1}{2}[-\cos(x_0+ct_0)+\cos(x_0-ct_0)]$

Hence the final solution is $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[\cos(x_0+ct_0)-\cos(x_0-ct_0)]+\frac{1}{2}[\cos(x_0+ct)-\cos(x_0-ct)-2cu(x_0,t_0)]$

Is it correct?

This is the first time I use formula (1), so if something can be improved don't hesitate to suggest.

**Edit**

Apparently the solution is wrong because I had to calculate the double integral over the area of the triangle and not the contour integral, that's what my professor said, but I don't know why, I didn't understand why. Could someone explain why is that?

I still don't see why application of Green theorem it's not correct in the double integral.

Comment: First of all, you have $x$ on LHS, and $x_0$ on RHS.

Comment: The short answer is no. I can't check your integral, but you can easily that the particular (non-homogeneous) solution is $v = xt^3/6$, which satisfies $v(x,0)=v_t(x,0)=0$. The remaining homogeneous part is d'Alembert's solution as usual.

Comment: @Dylan I don't understand why not. I just applied the given formula. The integral of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$, and for the integral over the triangle I split in 3 contour integrals (they were integrated over the sides of the triangle)

Comment: @user539887 what does that mean?

Comment: The RHS seems not to depend on $x$.

Comment: The integral of $\sin x$ is ${-\cos x}$

Comment: @Dylan well just 1 typo..

Comment: @Isa Green's theorem states that$$\iint\limits_D\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int\limits_{\partial D}(P\,\mathrm dx+Q\,\mathrm dy).$$What exactly are $P$ and $Q$ when you apply the theorem?

Comment: I too would like to see more of your steps for your Green's theorem integral evaluation

Comment: @AlexFrancisco In this case is $\iint_\Delta (u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx})dA=\int_{\partial \Delta} u_tdx+c^2u_xdt$

Comment: @AlexFrancisco so $P=u_t$ and $Q=u_x$

Comment: @Dylan :O ok, it's almost an entire sheet of paper (calculations..), I'll try to post it as soon as possible:)

Comment: Why not just integrate the actual function? $u_t$ and $u_x$ are unknown

Comment: @Dylan Because my professor (class example) split like $\iint_\Delta (u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx})dA=\int_{\partial \Delta} u_tdx+c^2u_xdt$ and then 3 integrals born and their limits were the contour of the triangle, and I just followed his method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of steps missing in your work, so I can't reliably tell you exactly what you did wrong. But I can tell you that most of it is wrong.

Here's the "usual" way to evaluate the area integral

$$ \frac{1}{2c}\iint_{D} ys \ dyds $$

The sides of the triangle $D(y,s)$ are given by

\begin{align} 
&S_1\{(x-ct,0)\to(x+ct,0)\} &&: s = 0 \\
&S_2\{(x+ct,0)\to (x,t)\} &&: y = x + c(t-s) \\
&S_3\{(x,t)\to(x-ct,0)\} &&: y = x - c(t-s) \end{align}

Then

\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{2c}\iint_{D} ys \ dyds &= \frac{1}{2c}\int_{0}^{t} \int_{x-c(t-s)}^{x+c(t-s)} ys\ dyds \\
&= \frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t \frac{\big[(x+c(t-s)\big]^2 - \big[x-c(t-s)\big]^2}{2}s\ ds \\
&= \frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t \big[{2c}x(t-s)\big]s\  ds \\
&= \int_0^t x(ts-s^2)\ ds \\
&= x\left(\frac{t^3}{2} - \frac{t^3}{3}\right) \\
&= \frac{xt^3}{6}
\end{align}

---

**Green's theorem method:** You need to find two functions $M$ and $N$ such that
$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = xt $$

These functions need not be unique, so we can arbitrarily choose
$$ M(x,t) = 0, \quad N(x,t) = -\frac{xt^2}{2} $$

Then

$$ \iint_D \left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial s} \right) dyds = \int_{\partial D} Ndy + Mds = \int_{\partial D} -\frac{ys^2}{2}dy $$

Following the boundary of the triangle in the counter clockwise direction, we have to split the integral into

\begin{align} 
\int_{\partial D} -\frac{ys^2}{2}dy &= \int_{S_1} -\frac{ys^2}{2}dy + \int_{S_2}-\frac{ys^2}{2}dy + \int_{S_3}-\frac{ys^2}{2}dy \\
&= 0 + \int_{x+ct}^{x} -\frac{\big[x+c(t-s)\big]s^2}{2}(-c\ ds) + \int_{x}^{x-ct} -\frac{\big[x-c(t-s)\big]s^2}{2}(c\ ds) \\
&= \frac{c}{2}\int_{x+ct}^{x} \big[x+c(t-s)\big]s^2\ ds - \frac{c}{2}\int_{x}^{x-ct} \big[x-c(t-s)\big]s^2\ ds
\end{align}

You can finish the integral if you want to, but this shows why using Green's theorem here is not a good idea. You get a bigger mess than the one you started with

---

Combined with the homogeneous piece (which is trivial to evaluate), the correct solution is

$$ y(x,t) = \frac{xt^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2c}\big[\cos(x-ct) - \cos(x+ct) \big] $$

Comment: How are this two columns related $\begin{align} 
&S_1\{(x-ct,0)\to(x+ct,0)\} &&: s = 0 \\
&S_2\{(x+ct,0)\to (x,t)\} &&: y = x + c(t-s) \\
&S_3\{(x,t)\to(x-ct,0)\} &&: y = x - c(t-s) \end{align}$ ? , I think I understand where they come from separately but seems like you did an implication from one to the other

Comment: So in general Green Theorem method will be complicated to solve this exercises?

Comment: These are lines in $(y,s)$ space going through the two points indicated. For example $S_2$ has a slope of $-c$, so the formula is $y-x = -c(s-t)$ and so on

Comment: As for the Green's method you did in class, I'm still not entirely sure what that involves, unless you give a specific example

Comment: Why to use another space, i.e. the $(y,s)$ space?

Comment: I'd upload a photo of the calculations I did in class, but unfortunately are not in english so I don't think you'll understand what I did, I'll translate them later

Answer (score 1):

2 method

- Let $u_1$ is solution of the problem

$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+xt,\quad u(x,0)=0,\quad u_t(x,0)=0.\qquad (1)$$
$u_2$ is solution of the problem
$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx},\quad u(x,0)=0,\quad u_t(x,0)=\sin(x).\qquad (2)$$
Then
$$u=u_1+u_2.$$

- The solution of  (1) is sought in the form $$u=v(t)\,x$$ Substitution this in $(1)$ yields

$$v''(t)=t,\;v(0)=0,\;v'(0)=0,$$
$$v(t)=\frac{t^3}{6},$$
$$u_1=\frac{t^3x}{6}$$

- The solution of  (2) is sought in the form $$u=v(t)\sin(x)$$ Substitution this in $(2)$ yields

$$v''(t)+c^2v(t)=0,\;v(0)=0,\;v'(0)=1,$$
$$v(t)=\frac{\sin(ct)}{c},$$
$$u_2=\frac{\sin(ct)}{c}\sin(x)$$

- $$u=u_1+u_2=\frac{t^3x}{6}+\frac{\sin(ct)}{c}\sin(x)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help Aleksas, I was checking the solutions and I don't know why your answer doesn't match with this answer $y(x,t) = \frac{xt^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2c}\big[\cos(x-ct) - \cos(x+ct) \big]$?

Comment: are they equivalent?

Comment: @Isa $\cos A-\cos B=-2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [IVP Wave Equation $u_{tt} = 4u_{xx} + \sin(ct)\cos(x)$ (PDE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307188):

Let $\begin{cases}p=x+ct\\q=x-ct\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_x=u_pp_x+u_qq_x=u_p+u_q$

$u_{xx}=(u_p+u_q)_x=(u_p+u_q)_pp_x+(u_p+u_q)_qq_x=u_{pp}+u_{pq}+u_{pq}+u_{qq}=u_{pp}+2u_{pq}+u_{qq}$

$u_t=u_pp_t+u_qq_t=cu_p-cu_q$

$u_{tt}=(cu_p-cu_q)_t=(cu_p-cu_q)_pp_t+(cu_p-cu_q)_qq_t=c^2u_{pp}-c^2u_{pq}-c^2u_{pq}+c^2u_{qq}=c^2u_{pp}-2c^2u_{pq}+c^2u_{qq}$

$\therefore c^2u_{pp}-2c^2u_{pq}+c^2u_{qq}=c^2u_{pp}+2c^2u_{pq}+c^2u_{qq}+\dfrac{(p+q)(p-q)}{4c}$

$-4c^2u_{pq}=\dfrac{p^2-q^2}{4c}$

$u_{pq}=\dfrac{q^2-p^2}{16c^3}$

$u(p,q)=f(p)+g(q)+\dfrac{pq^3-p^3q}{48c^3}$

$u(p,q)=f(p)+g(q)+\dfrac{pq(q^2-p^2)}{48c^3}$

$u(x,t)=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)+\dfrac{c^2xt^3-x^3t}{12c^2}$

Answer (score 0):

see:

Dean G. Duffy, Transform methods for solving partial differential equations, 2nd edition, Example 2.3.1, page 141

Ravi P. Agarwal, Donal O’Regan, Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations, Springer, 2009, Lecture 48

Example. We solve wave equation

$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+xt,\quad -\infty<x<\infty,\quad t>0$,

subject to initial conditions

$u(x,0)=0,\; u_t(x,0)=\sin (x),\quad -\infty<x<\infty$.

Taking the Laplace transform and substituting the initial conditions, we obtain
ordinary differential equation
$${{c}^{2}}\, \left( \frac{{{d}^{2}}}{d {{x}^{2}}} \operatorname{U}\left( x,s\right) \right) -{{s}^{2}} \operatorname{U}\left( x,s\right) =-\sin{(x)}-\frac{x}{{{s}^{2}}}$$
with boundary conditions
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}|U(x,s)|<\infty,\;\lim_{x\to \infty}|U(x,s)|<\infty.\qquad(1)$$

Solving this ordinary differential equation,
$$U(x,s)=\frac{\sin{(x)}}{{{s}^{2}}+{{c}^{2}}}+\frac{x}{{{s}^{4}}}+C_1\, {{e}^{\frac{s x}{c}}}+C_2\, {{e}^{-\frac{s x}{c}}}$$
From boundary conditions $(1)$ we get $C_1=C_2=0$.

Then
$$U(x,s)=\frac{\sin{(x)}}{{{s}^{2}}+{{c}^{2}}}+\frac{x}{{{s}^{4}}}$$

Final step is the inversion of the Laplace transform $U(x,s)$. We get answer
$$u=\frac{\sin{\left( c t\right) } \sin{(x)}}{c}+\frac{{{t}^{3}} x}{6}$$

Comment: I have no idea what you did here :/

Comment: I haven't seen Laplace method in the course